# Como mostrar o conteúdo de um SMS recebido no Android em um diálogo de texto?

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para Android que envia um pedido via SMS para um equipamento remoto e recebe de volta uma resposta, também via SMS, a qual deve ser apresentada para o usuário.

Para receber o SMS utilizei o seguinte código, que implementa `SmsReceiver` a partir de um `BroadcastReceiver`, apresentando o conteúdo da mensagem recebida por meio de um `Toast`:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Como o `Toast` é uma mensagem temporária e some automaticamente, fica difícil para o usuário ler o conteúdo com calma, então pensei em apresentá-lo por meio de um diálogo com um botão OK. Dessa forma, pensei em utilizar um `DialogFragment`, mas, de acordo com várias respostas no Stack Overflow (em inglês) como:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835160/how-can-i-display-a-dialog-from-an-android-broadcast-receiver

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229951/how-to-raise-an-alert-dialog-from-broadcastreceiver-class

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667790/showing-an-alertdialog-from-receiver

e outras - ficou claro que este diálogo não pode ser diretamente instanciado a partir de um `BroadcastReceiver` (classe base utilizada para receber o SMS) mas sim a partir de uma `Activity`. Porém, [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3835524/1007502) (também em inglês), explica que, se você registrar seu `BroadcastReceiver` na atividade através do método `registerReceiver` ao invés de tê-lo declarado no Manifest - que é o que está feito atualmente em minha aplicação - eu poderia simplesmente usar esta mesma atividade para apresentar meu diálogo.

Como sou meio novato ainda no Java, como faço isso? Devo instanciar minha classe `SmsReceiver` como uma classe privada da minha `Activity` e então chamar o `registerReceiver` pra ela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após várias horas de pesquisa e tentativas, finalmente consegui o resultado desejado, que realmente baseou-se na utilização de um `BroadcastReceiver` instanciado diretamente em minha atividade ao invés de declarado via `Manifest`. Resumindo o problema, considere que minha atividade se chama `MainActivity`. Nela, declarei uma variável privada `message`, que se destina a receber o texto proveniente do corpo do SMS. No método `onResume` da atividade é então instanciado o `BroadcastReceiver`, o qual traz a implementação do método `onReceive` já montando a String na variável `message` da atividade (como o `BroadcastReceiver` agora é um objeto de `MainActivity` ele tem acesso às variáveis privadas dela), a qual por sua vez é passada ao `TextViewFragment` (via objeto `Bundle`) para ser mostrada no diálogo por ele instanciado:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    //Objeto responsável pela recepção de SMS
    BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver;
    //String destinada a receber o conteúdo do SMS, o qual deverá ser apresentado
    //ao usuário por meio de um diálogo de texto
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Instancia BroadcastReceiver responsável pelo recebimento de SMS
        smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //Obtém a mensagem do SMS recebido
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                message = "";
                if (bundle != null)
                {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        message += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                        message += "\n";
                    }
                }
                //Instancia fragmento responsável pelo diálogo que 
                //apresentará o conteúdo do SMS ao usuário
                Bundle bundleEventReport = new Bundle();
                bundleEventReport.putInt("title_id", R.string.label_events_report);
                bundleEventReport.putString("text", message);
                TextViewFragment eventReportFragment = new TextViewFragment();
                eventReportFragment.setArguments(bundleEventReport);
                eventReportFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "eventReport");
            }
        };
        //Registra o objeto BroadcastReceiver como recebedor de SMS
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver,
                         new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
    }

}
```