# Como saber o SMS recebido no Android?

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um cadastro onde um passo do cadastro é a autenticação do número via sms, até consigo fazer o envio do sms com o seguinte código abaixo, mas quando vou fazer a leitura, pega o ultimo sms recebido, não aquele que meu sistema está enviando

```
String message = code.getRandonNumberCode(4);
   String number =  txtTelephone.getText().toString();
   SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
   smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,message,null,null);
```

Para fazer a leitura de alguma forma estava tentando algo do tipo, ele até le o sms, mas le o sms antes de receber de fato o sms que meu sistema gerou

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null,null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    txtCodeReceived.setText(cursor.getString(12));
```

Tambédm tentei criar um BroadcastListener com algo parecido como esse link [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9777/como-mostrar-o-conte%C3%BAdo-de-um-sms-recebido-no-android-em-um-di%C3%A1logo-de-texto) mas como está depreciado não recebo nada no onReceive no BroadcastListener.

Comment: [Depreciado ou obsoleto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178138/o-que-%c3%a9-um-c%c3%b3digo-depreciado/178152#comment368172_178138)? Aparece alguma mensagem dizendo que está obsoleto ou depracated ou é apenas suposição? Note que para usar o BroadcastReceiver é necessário ajustar o AndroidManifest para usar o `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`. A resposta que postou só tem parte do que deve ser feito pq o problema lá não é sobre receber, é outra coisa, vou ver se já existe resposta aqui no site sobre ler sms no android, se não irei tentar formular uma.

Comment: Nao, isso na proproa documentação la dessa resposta, mostra que o metodo createFromPdu está depreciado

Comment: Então, eu coloco o android.provider la tb no código, não funciona

Comment: Ok, createFromPdu não está depreciado, mas sim depracated, em Português, obsoleto. Mas se seguir a doc mesmo verá que o android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED não é obsoleto, provavelmente só mudou o meio de ler o getExtras. Como estou no celular não tenho como formular um exemplo, assim que possível volto aqui e verifico tudo para uma possível resposta. Até

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento valeu man, vou trabalhando em outras partes da task.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que o BroadcastReceiver seja o suficiente para o seu caso.
Os campos *body* e *identificador* você pode adicionar um código de identificação, por ex:

> Meu Aplicativo Token: 123456

Dessa forma você sempre irá pegar o sms que enviou.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "SmsReceiver";
private static final String PDUS = "pdus";

private OnSmsReceivedListener mOnSmsReceivedListener;

public SmsReceiver(OnSmsReceivedListener onSmsReceivedListener) {
    mOnSmsReceivedListener = onSmsReceivedListener;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    try {
        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(PDUS)) {
            final Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get(PDUS);

            for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                String messageBody = sms.getDisplayMessageBody();
                String smsSender = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

                if (messageBody.contains("Meu Aplicativo Token"))) {
                    String verificationCode = messageBody.replace("Meu Aplicativo Token", "").trim();
                    mOnSmsReceivedListener.onSmsReceived(verificationCode, smsSender);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "[onReceive]Exception message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Achei um jeito não exatamente com broadcast listener mas dps vou implementar sua soluçao!

Comment: O AP (@gabrielfalieri) mencionou que o [`createFromPdu(byte[])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage#createFromPdu(byte[])) está obsoleto, no caso tem que mudar para `SmsMessage createFromPdu (byte[] pdu, String format)` para informar o formato.

Comment: que estranho, herdou de `android.telephony.SmsMessage`?

Comment: Está no link da documentação, tem que especificar o format, fora que também é necessário adicionar as configurações no AndroidManifest. Foi por isso que apenas comentei e não respondi, porque é algo que precisa ser testado antes de formular uma resposta e seguir a documentação para adequar.